# expected ')' before '!' token in c

Tags: c, error-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
int i,l,n;
int w[1000];
int h[1000];
scanf ("%d",&l);
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     scanf("%d %d",&w[i],&h[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if((w[i]<l)!!(h[i]<l))
     printf("UPLOAD ANOTHER\n");
    else(w[i]>=l&&h[i]>=l)
      {
          if(w[i]==h[i])
          printf("ACCEPTED\n");
          else
          printf ("CROP IT\n");
      }
}
            return 0;
}
```

As I am new to coding these lines of code showing me error :-

> In function 'main':
>   18:20: error: expected ')' before '!' token
>   21:11: error: expected ';' before '{' token

Comment: With `!!` do you really mean logical or using `||`?

Answer (score 3):

In the first IF statement, you are using !! as OR, but you should be using ||.

Compilers can not know what you are trying to do, but they can tell you what they are expecting based on what they have read so far. Because you used !!, which is the NOT symbol (twice), the compiler only knows that your expression is syntactically incorrect. In this case, it is saying that given this unexpected unary NOT operator, the current expression should have been closed with a ')' symbol.

Compilers are not mind readers, so they cannot know that you meant || (logical OR). Some compilers used to try to guess (and even fix) such typos, and they only made things worse. PL/1 comes to mind, it would attempt to fix compiler errors and this drove people crazy.

The second error on line 21 is because you placed an expression after the "else" which makes no sense to the compiler which is expecting a statement to execute at this point. You can fix this by replacing "else" with "else if". This works because IF is a statement, and that statement expects an expression next. I think this is what you intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i,l,n;    
 int w[1000];    
 int h[1000];

 scanf ("%d",&l);
 scanf("%d",&n);

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     scanf("%d %d",&w[i],&h[i]);
    }

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if((w[i]<l)||(h[i]<l))
         printf("UPLOAD ANOTHER\n");
        else if (w[i]>=l&&h[i]>=l)
          {
              if(w[i]==h[i])
              printf("ACCEPTED\n");
              else
              printf ("CROP IT\n");
          }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Once you get more experience with C, you will recognise this kind of error easily, a simple typo can confused the compiler. Good luck!

Comment: thank u ...for correcting me ,i forgotten   about this :-)

Comment: what about this one  21:11: error: expected ';' before '{' token  ??

Comment: I have updated my answer. You placed an expression after the ELSE, but c syntax expects a statement after ELSE. You should have wrote "else if".